# USe php include inside of tabs

Tags: php, tabs, include

The tab script is used like that:

```
{tab Tab Title 1}

Text

{tab Tab Title 2}

Text

{/tabs}
```

I need a PHP script in every tab so I tried to include the PHP scripts like that:

```
{tab Tab Title 1}

<?php include ("info.php"); ?>

{tab Tab Title 2}

<?php include ("info2.php"); ?>

{/tabs}
```

The problem is. If I include more than one PHP script I get a blank page. The problem isn't the tab script, because I tried it with several ones and always the same result - a blank page. Any ideas how to include multiple PHP scripts in tabs?

Comment: A blank page probably means that one of the files you're trying to `include` has a parse error. Be sure that you have enabled error reporting. The problem is not related to tabs.

Comment: Try to put 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); 

ini_set('display_errors','on);`

Comment: Make sure the contents in those included scripts have the correct opening and closing tags. Try including one first to see if problem persist and debug from there. You just be missing some opening and closing tags

Answer (score 0):

1 - Look inside the apache log for debugging
2 - Try to include the scripts one by one and see if all of them work fine

Comment: The scripts are working fine if I include them inside the tabs for their own. Only if I include more than one the blank page happens. I tried your solution, but no effect.

Comment: try `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);` and debug the php scripts, all points a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

Two things can happen :
1. The two php scripts are individually alright but is overlapping  tags when put together.
2. Your html is somehow coming inside php tags